# Can't remove bogo-python in keyboard indicator

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, ibus

I'm using `LTS 16.04` .I already remove `ibus-bogo` but it's indicator still remain and I've stucked in it everytime I changed my input. Could you guys please help me remove this? [Link picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmhJs.png). 
The Text Entry only has English input only!. When I reinstalled `ibus-bogo`, Text Entry still only has English input only. I tried add and remove but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suggestion would be:

1. Reinstall `ibus-bogo`
2. Log out and log in again
3. Go to *Text Entry* and remove the item
4. Uninstall `ibus-bogo`

However, since the OP reported that this was not sufficient, and since he only wants the *English (US)* keyboard layout, the solution was to change `~/.config/dconf/user` via this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'us')]"
```